# Flexbox item breaking out of container

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Without resizing my monitor my layout looks like this (which is pretty much correct)

[image]

However, when I resize it the amount breaks out of the container

[image]

I want the green area, the main text, to keep shrinking as the text gets longer or the screen is resized. I don't want anything else to resize and esp. don't want it to break out of the container. The green area has plenty of room to be resized.

Here's a link to my demo http://jsbin.com/potalu/1/edit

If you want to look at the CSS here:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
.transaction {
  background:#ccc;
  display:flex;
  align-content: flex-center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
  .checkbox {
    background: lighten(red, 40%);
    width: 30px;
   }
    .checkbox .box {
      width: 10px;
      height:10p;
      border: 1px solid orange;
    }
  .date {
    background: lighten(blue, 30%);
    width: 25px;
  }
  .description {
    background: lighten(green, 60%);
    padding-right: 10px;
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
    .description-wrapper { 
      white-space:nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis; 

    }
  .amount {
    background: lighten(purple, 60%);
  }
  .txn-amount {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:right;
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add:

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

to all areas you don't want to be shrinked (.checkbox, .date, .amount) and set .description to

```
flex-shrink: 1;
```

see: http://jsbin.com/qolajanetesi/1/edit?css